# SwiftUI: Toggle control is changing its location

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11, swift5

I have a very simple form where I list CommentViewControl in a list.

```
struct CommentViewControl: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            AnsweredBar(question.IsAnswered)
                .frame(width: 5)
                .offset(x: -10)
            Text("Any Text")
                .font(.caption)
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .frame(width: CGFloat(50 * UIScreen.main.bounds.width/100),
                       alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .offset(x: -16)
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: $toggleControl) {
                Text("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is the location of toggle control is randomly changing for each line.

What can cause such random location issue. I have multiple tabs, when I change the tab and come back to previous one; some other toggle change its place. it is very inconsistent. See the image below.

[image: Toggles are randomly replaced on the list]

Comment: Your code seems incomplete, what is toggleControl? It's not defined anywhere. Could you also include the View that uses CommentViewControl?

Comment: What happens of you add `.labelsHidden()` to the `Toggle`? I.e., `Toggle("", isOn: $toggleControl).labelsHidden()`

Comment: I tried to put the brief of the code. I guess I removed the toggleControl State variable by mistake.

Comment: labelsHidden() didnt help but after adding .id(UUID().uuidString) the interface is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either update or caching issue... try the following

```
Toggle(isOn: $toggleControl)
{
    Text("")
}.id(UUID().uuidString)
```

Comment: This perfectly worked. But what is the logic here. How did it help?

Comment: List cashes its rows, but changing '.id' it is indicated explicitly that  content is new and needs to be redrawn.